# Multiselect checked change by condition

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using multiselect in a jqGrid. When I click on a row then the row is selected and checked. I want it to whenever I click on a row in the 'onSelectRow' event base it on a condition, and change the checked state of the row (if false set to unchecked).
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent selection by returning false from `beforeSelectRow`. You can implement any custom condition here.